# How to create nested array ancestors recursively in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, nested

I'm using PHP 7.3.
I want to create a nested array that each item must contain its own ancestors.

**Original Array:**

```
[
    [
        id => 1,
        parentId => ""
    ],
    [
        id => 2,
        parentId => 1
    ],
    [
        id => 3,
        parentId => 2
    ]
]
```

**Required Array:**

```
[
    [
        id => 1,
        parentId => "",
        ancestors => []
    ],
    [
        id => 2,
        parentId => 1,
        ancestors => [
            [
                id => 1,
                parentId => "",
                ancestors => []
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        id => 3,
        parentId => 2,
        ancestors => [
                [
                    id => 1,
                    parentId => "",
                    ancestors => []
                ],
                [
                    id => 2,
                    parentId => 1,
                    ancestors => [
                        [
                            id => 1,
                            parentId => "",
                            ancestors => []
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841921/11152632) solution, but I think this problem is different.
Any help / guidance is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196157/create-array-tree-from-array-list

Comment: Read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157243/how-to-create-nested-php-arrays-recursively

Comment: Why would you need that? You can use original ancestor by it's id (parentId of a child).

Comment: These are creating children, but I want to create ancestors.
@ArashShiri

Comment: I have to provide this output. @SalimIbrogimov

Comment: @AmirRezaAzizi Are entries always in the "ancestors first" order? i.e. Could entry 10 be an ancestor of entry 2?

Comment: Sometimes you need to change the way you want to get things done. What you're requesting is redundant and wasteful use of resources. I suggest you to reconsider what you want from your script.

Comment: @Jeto Yes, It will use in file manager and each item has a path. like: /var/www/html/file.php

Comment: @AmirRezaAzizi Not sure exactly how that answers my question though.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov Yes, I know that it's redundant, but our team needs it for file manager and I should handle it.

Comment: @Jeto Yes, they are always in the "ancestors first" order and second question's answer in No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build a tree from a flat array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840319/build-a-tree-from-a-flat-array-in-php)

Comment: No, but the answer from Jeto is the correct way. @orustammanapov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first make use of `array_column` to group your entries by ID, then `array_reduce` to build your new array that includes ancestors (without altering the base one):

```
$entriesById = array_column($array, null, 'id');
    
$entriesWithAncestors = array_reduce(
  $entriesById,

  static function (array $result, array $entry) use ($entriesById): array {
    $result[$entry['id']] = $entry + ['ancestors' => []];
    $parentId = $entry['parentId'];
    while (isset($result[$parentId])) {
      $result[$entry['id']]['ancestors'][] = $result[$parentId];
      $parentId = $entriesById[$parentId]['parentId'] ?? null;
    }
    return $result;
  }, 

  []
);

print_r($entriesWithAncestors);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/L4e6P)**

Note that this assumes parent entries are always present before their children in the original array, as you mentioned in the comments.